# Serializer - speed of Kryo, API/functionality like FlexJson

Tags: java, json, serialization

Tile says it all.  I love the functionality of FlexJson (clean API, backwards/forward data compatibility, ability to easily include/exclude data and transform it) but would love something as fast as Kryo (or faster than FlexJson).  What are my options?  Data can be binary.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)?